# cant send from server to whatsapp twice

Tags: node.js, whatsapp

I'm trying to get message from the server and send it to the whatsapp  using whatsapp-web.js in node js first time message is sent but the second time message didn't send until i restart the server
where is the bug in the code

this us the logic that gets the message from server and pass it to whatsapp sending function

```
pp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
    const ticket = req.body.name;
    sendwhts(ticket)
    res.send(`Hello, ${ticket}!`);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on http://localhost:3000');
});

//this is the fun that send the message


function sendwhts (meg){
  const client = new Client({
    
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth(),
    dataPath: 'auth'
});



client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
    client.getChats().then(chats =>{
        const MyGroup=chats.find(
            (chat)=> chat.name ==='test'
            //Ftth activation
        );
        client.sendMessage(MyGroup.id._serialized,"meg");
    })
});


client.initialize();
}
```